# "Downloading proxy script" even though "Automatically detect settings" is disabled?

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, google-chrome, proxy

I had just seen "Downloading proxy script" message in Chrome status bar, and that's highly suspicious, and seems to be impossible, because I had disabled proxy automatic configuration.

I know exactly what proxy scripts are, I am a Windows power user and I know a lot about PowerShell and Python.

I live in China, I was born here but I am no fan of the CCP, quite the contrary, in fact. I use VPN to browse the free internet, and my ISP is really antagonistic about this, it being part of the GFW, tries to disrupt my network connection extremely frequently.

I have disabled proxy automatic configuration because I think it would be detrimental to my freedom, my ISP could send PACs to my computer that makes accessing international internet harder. But I had just seen "Downloading proxy script" in Chrome's status bar while "Automatically detect settings" is disabled, according to what I have seen online this shouldn't be possible. I saw the message during yet another attempt to disrupt my VPN connection by my ISP, I couldn't access anything during this period, and I have written a Python script that monitors my network connection and actively combats the disruptions 24/7, the problem was fixed in mere seconds.

Just how can this happen?

I have disabled "Automatically detect settings":

[image]

Using the following commands:

```
New-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
New-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Control Panel" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" -Name AutoDetect -Type DWord -Value 0
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" -Name AutoDetect -Type DWord -Value 1
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Control Panel" -Name Autoconfig -Type DWord -Value 1
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" -Name AutoConfigURL -Type String -Value ""
```

Yet I had seen the message, I really did, I wasn't fast enough to take a screenshot. Shouldn't it be impossible?

I had inspected chrome://net-internals/#proxy yet I found nothing:

[image]

How did this happen? Should I be concerned?